# Ubuntu One won't synchronize pictures folder

Tags: ubuntu-one

When I try to sync `/home/tyler/Pictures` I get  `could not enable /home/tyler/Pictures for syncing to Ubuntu One`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you try to create a synchronized folder from something that is not an actual directory inside your home (if it is, for example, a symlink to somewhere else), or if it is a subdirectory of a synchronized folder, then the creation will fail.

If you try to do the same thing from the Terminal, you should get a slightly more verbose error message; e.g.,

```
$ u1sdtool --create-folder=/home/tyler/Pictures
FolderCreateError: UDFs can not be a symlink (path=/home/tyler/Pictures)
```

(UDFs is what we Ubuntu One developers call synchronized folders). If the output is instead

```
$ u1sdtool --create-folder=/home/tyler/Pictures/
FolderCreateError: UDFs can not be nested (path=/home/tyler/Pictures)
```

then you can use `u1sdtool --list-folders` to see what synchronized folder you have already that is a subdirectory of `Pictures`.

Comment: is Pictures a symlink? when i do ls -l i don't see it as one

Comment: please try running `u1sdtool` on the commandline, as above. I expanded my answer a little bit.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently there is a bug where ubuntu one client in ubuntu mistakes folders created by ubuntu one mobile as the /Pictures folder.  Here's the bug, I suspect bad handling of spaces/dashes in a string comparison:

Try to sync Pictures folder:

```
jonathan@laptop:~/Pictures$ u1sdtool --create-folder=/home/jonathan/Pictures
FolderCreateError: UDFs can not be nested (path=/home/jonathan/Pictures)
```

No nested folders:

```
jonathan@laptop:~/Pictures$ u1sdtool --list-folders
Folder list:
  id=b60eca52-dce7-4b04-916d-b469ba09c847 subscribed=True path=/home/jonathan/Music
  id=252a0d67-212c-4a5d-a50b-f1c9142dc074 subscribed=True path=/home/jonathan/Pictures - DROID3
  id=f62bdf1f-d7b6-4b8e-9490-59199b51f86b subscribed=True path=/home/jonathan/Pictures - Nikon S8100
  id=cc2e243d-6dc8-464f-b429-b7d7e7a2d5c7 subscribed=True path=/home/jonathan/Pictures - Eris
```

Empty Pictures folder:

```
jonathan@laptop:~/Pictures$ ls -l -a
total 20
drwxr-xr-x  2 jonathan jonathan  4096 2011-08-10 09:57 .
drwx------ 65 jonathan jonathan 16384 2011-09-17 16:50 ..
```

It's pretty annoying, but since auto-upload is not working on my Driod3, I ended up deleting all automatic cloud folders and the issue went away.

Answer (score 0):

This was probably cause by bug [#854776](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntuone-client/+bug/854776). If you update and try again, does it work?